# Python pull values from nested dictionary for args in function call

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I'm writing a bit of Python code to read in JSON data containing object types and parameters. I essentially need to run through this data and call one of a few functions that, using those parameters, creates a new, unique object each time to be used later. The JSON data looks like this:

```
 {
 "objects" : {
  "1" : {
    "type" : "sphere",
    "radius" : "100",
    "centerx" : "30",
    "centery" : "40",
    "centerz" : "50"
},
  "2" : {
    "type" : "box",
    "lengthx" : "30",
    "lengthy" : "40",
    "lengthz" : "50",
    "centerx" : "60",
    "centery" : "70",
    "centerz" : "80"
},
  "3" : {
    "type" : "cone",
    "length" : "30",
    "radius1" : "40",
    "radius2" : "50",
    "centerx" : "60",
    "centery" : "70",
    "centerz" : "80"
},
  "4" : {
    "type" : "cylinder",
    "length" : "30",
    "radius" : "40",
    "centerx" : "60",
    "centery" : "70",
    "centerz" : "80"
    }
   }
}
```

Here's my updated code as it stands now:

```
display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display()
with open('C:\Users\willi_000\Documents\Code\document (9).json') as   data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

funcs = {
    'sphere': BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere,
    'box': BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox,
    'cone': BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone,
    'cylinder': BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder
}
shapes = []
for index, kwargs in data['objects'].iteritems():
    mypoint = gp_Pnt(float(kwargs.pop('centerx')),     float(kwargs.pop('centery')), float(kwargs.pop('centerz')))
    function = funcs[kwargs.pop('type')]
    #print mypoint
    #print function
    myshape = function(mypoint,float(**kwargs)).Shape()
    start_display()
```

And night now I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/willi_000/Documents/Code/dumbbox.py", line 32, in <module>
    myshape = function(mypoint,**kwargs).Shape()
TypeError: keywords must be strings"
```

For reference, here are two examples of what the make functions are expecting

```
BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere::BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere  (   const gp_Pnt &  Center,
const Standard_Real     R )     


BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox::BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox    (   const gp_Pnt &  P,
const Standard_Real     dx,
const Standard_Real     dy,
const Standard_Real     dz )
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add all of the `Shapes` to a list.

```
data ={
 "objects" : {
  "1" : {
    "type" : "sphere",
    "radius" : "100",
    "centerx" : "30",
    "centery" : "40",
    "centerz" : "50"
},
  "2" : {
    "type" : "box",
    "lengthx" : "30",
    "lengthy" : "40",
    "lengthz" : "50",
    "centerx" : "60",
    "centery" : "70",
    "centerz" : "80"
},
  "3" : {
    "type" : "cone",
    "length" : "30",
    "radius1" : "40",
    "radius2" : "50",
    "centerx" : "60",
    "centery" : "70",
    "centerz" : "80"
},
  "4" : {
    "type" : "cylinder",
    "length" : "30",
    "radius" : "40",
    "centerx" : "60",
    "centery" : "70",
    "centerz" : "80"
    }
   }
}

funcs = {
    'sphere': BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere,
    'box': BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox,
    'cone': BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone,
    'cylinder': BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder
}
shapes = []
for index, kwargs in data['objects'].iteritems():
    function = funcs[kwargs.pop('type')]
    shapes.append(function(**kwargs).Shape())
```

I had to fake the functions and the `.Shape()` part, but it works for me.

---

### Update

As per the comment (by @williamwatts), I think this is what you want. Replace the `for` loop with this:

```
for index, kwargs in data['objects'].iteritems():
    function = funcs[kwargs.pop('type')]
    kwargs = {k:float(v) for k, v in kwargs.iteritems()}
    mypoint = gp_Pnt(kwargs.pop('centerx'), kwargs.pop('centery'), kwargs.pop('centerz'))
    myshape = function(mypoint, **kwargs).Shape()
    shapes.append(myshape)
    display.DisplayShape(myshape, update=True)
```

This assumes that all shapes will have `centerx`, `centery` and `centerz` attributes.

---

### Update 2

Since the functions are defined using *args, you cannot use keyword arguments. You will have to use this instead:

```
funcs = {
    'sphere': {
        'function': BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere,
        'argnames': ['radius']
    },
    'box': {
        'function': BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox,
        'argnames': ['lengthx', 'lengthy', 'lengthz']
    },
    'cone': {
        'function': BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone,
        'argnames': ['length', 'radius1', 'radius2']
    },
    'cylinder': {
        'function': BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder,
        'argnames': ['length', 'radius']
    }
}
shapes = []
for index, kwargs in data['objects'].iteritems():
    print kwargs
    shapeinfo = funcs[kwargs.pop('type')]
    kwargs = {k:float(v) for k, v in kwargs.iteritems()}
    mypoint = gp_Pnt(kwargs.pop('centerx'), kwargs.pop('centery'), kwargs.pop('centerz'))
    args = [kwargs[name] for name in shapeinfo['argnames']]
    myshape = shapeinfo['function'](mypoint, *args).Shape()
    shapes.append(myshape)
    display.DisplayShape(myshape, update=True)
```

This makes sure that the args are sent in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, you're definitely right about adding all the shapes to a list, and what you described is working well for me. Now I'm running to the next step in the problem. I need to call those functions (makebox etc) using the values in each nested dict as follows below, and calling those values when not all the same parameters are used by each type of function is proving tricky ' P1 = gp_Pnt(centerx, centery, centerz)
my_box2 = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(P1, lentghx,lengthy,lengthz).Shape()
display.DisplayShape(my_box2, update=True) '

Comment: @williamwatts I added an update, see if that works for you.

Comment: So I had to add casting the the mypoint arguments to floats as follows mypoint = gp_Pnt(float(kwargs.pop('centerx')) to get that to work, but now I'm getting "TypeError: keywords must be strings" on the myshape = function" line which is surprising to me.

Comment: @williamwatts That would seem to indicate that the dictionary keys are not always strings. Is that the case? Could you possibly update your question with your current code?

Comment: Updated with current code and some more info. Thanks!

Comment: @williamwatts I updated the last code block to cast all arguments to floats (except 'type' of course). I am not sure where that error is coming from since JSON can only have strings for keys. Can you try printing out `kwargs` before the `myshape = function(mypoint, **kwargs).Shape()` line?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too sure either. I added the print kwargs before the myshape line and got this:  'Display3d class successfully initialized.
 ########################################
{u'radius': 100.0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/willi_000/Documents/Code/dumbbox.py", line 32, in <module>
    myshape = function(mypoint, **kwargs).Shape()
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'radius''

Comment: @williamwatts That's a different (and easier to explain) error. After figuring out that this is OpenCascade, I looked at the API and the BRepPrimAPI_Make* functions are defined using `*args` meaning you can't use keyword args. I have added an update.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. I still have some tweaking to get this to do all I want but it's reading in multiple objects (at least of the sphere type for now) and parameters rendering them as desired. I'm off and running now. Thanks again!